# Incorrect buffer size returned by the default provider

Tags: java, android, encryption, aes-gcm

With Android 9 and API 28 the Bouncy Castle provider ("BC") is no longer supported and trying using it results in the `NoSuchAlgorithmException`. As per [the official blog post](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/03/cryptography-changes-in-android-p.html) from the Android the way to fix this is to not specify the provider at all.

However it seems that the default provider behaves differently from the Bouncy Castle provider - in the `DECRYPT_MODE` the `getOuptputSize` method returns a different value for the same parameter. The code below shows that the BC provider returns 35 while the default provider returns 51 when asking for the output size of the encrypted buffer of 51:

```
Cipher aesGCMCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding", "BC");
GCMParameterSpec gcmParameterSpec = new GCMParameterSpec(AES_KEY_SIZE_IN_BITS, new byte[12]);
aesGCMCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, aesSecretKey, gcmParameterSpec);
LOG.i("(Decrypt) BC provider output size: " + aesGCMCipher.getOutputSize(51));

Cipher defaultAesGCMCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding");
GCMParameterSpec defaultGcmParameterSpec = new GCMParameterSpec(AES_KEY_SIZE_IN_BITS, new byte[12]);
defaultAesGCMCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, aesSecretKey, defaultGcmParameterSpec);
LOG.i("(Decrypt) Default provider output size: " + defaultAesGCMCipher.getOutputSize(51));

// Ouptput:
(Decrypt) BC provider output size: 35
(Decrypt) Default provider output size: 51
```

Note that the values returned in the `ENCRYPT_MODE` are the same:

```
Cipher aesGCMCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding", "BC");
GCMParameterSpec gcmParameterSpec = new GCMParameterSpec(AES_KEY_SIZE_IN_BITS, new byte[12]);
aesGCMCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, aesSecretKey, gcmParameterSpec);
LOG.i("(Encrypt) BC provider output size: " + aesGCMCipher.getOutputSize(35));

Cipher defaultAesGCMCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding");
GCMParameterSpec defaultGcmParameterSpec = new GCMParameterSpec(AES_KEY_SIZE_IN_BITS, new byte[12]);
defaultAesGCMCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, aesSecretKey, defaultGcmParameterSpec);
LOG.i("(Encrypt) Default provider output size: " + defaultAesGCMCipher.getOutputSize(35));

// Output
(Encrypt) BC provider output size: 51
(Encrypt) Default provider output size: 51
```

Is the code for determining the size of the output buffer incorrect and needs to be rewritten or is it a bug in the implementation that requires a workaround?
Right now because the returned value is incorrect the allocated buffer is too big which results in corrupt messages (additional bytes appended to the message). It seems like a bug to me but I am hesitant to arbitrarily cut the last 16 bytes because if the bug is fixed the code will regress again.

Comment: The documentation is clear: *The actual output length of the next update or doFinal call may be smaller than the length returned by this method.*

Comment: I see. I thought that for GCM it was possible to determine the size of the decrypted message without actually looking at the encrypted message. In that case because I am using `doFinal` with byteBuffers it's seems I will need to use `.position()` and `.remaining()` to calculate the actual size of the message after decrypting.

Comment: It is possible, but the Cipher contract does not require that `getOutputSize()` return the exact output size even when it would be easy to do so. It only requires >=. You might file a bug report or feature request stating the result is acceptable but suboptimal.